# Unable to locate element using cypress

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

I am working on a chatbot using dialogflow. So in order to test it, we are using cypress.

I have the chatbot messenger, and I want to click in this button to expand my messenger.
[image]

Below is my test case:

```
    it('TC_01_Campaigns', () => {
        cy.visit('https://<some-random-address>.com/');
        cy.wait(4000);
        //cy.contains('widgetIcon')
        // cy.get('[id="widgetIcon"]')
        // cy.get('button[id="widgetIcon"]').click();
        cy.xpath('//*[@id="widgetIcon"]')
    })
```

I have tried out the commented out lines of codes. It just doesn't seem to work.

Below is the html code of the DOM:

```
<html><head><script src="https://static.dialogflow.com/common/messenger/webcomponentsjs/2.1.3/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script><script src="https://static.dialogflow.com/common/messenger/webcomponentsjs/2.1.3/webcomponents-loader.js"></script><style type="text/css">:root{--df-messenger-bot-message:#fff;--df-messenger-button-titlebar-color:#42a5f5;--df-messenger-button-titlebar-font-color:#fff;--df-messenger-chat-background-color:#fafafa;--df-messenger-font-color:rgba(0,0,0,.87);--df-messenger-input-box-color:#fff;--df-messenger-input-font-color:rgba(0,0,0,.87);--df-messenger-input-placeholder-font-color:#757575;--df-messenger-minimized-chat-close-icon-color:rgba(0,0,0,.87);--df-messenger-send-icon:#42a5f5;--df-messenger-user-message:#ddd;--df-messenger-chip-color:#fff;--df-messenger-chip-border-color:#e0e0e0}</style><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>
    <h1>Chatbot</h1>

    
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 5px;">
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
      <df-messenger chat-title="BR" agent-id="xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx" language-code="en" session-id="dfMessenger-43967287" api-uri="https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/v1/integrations/messenger/webhook"></df-messenger>
    </div>
  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/messenger-internal.min.js?v=4"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: In the HTML code of the DOM, you have provided. the button is not visible, isn't it? 
can you run this in your console $x("//button") and check if it gives any values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you post what error message you are getting when trying your code? This could help.

Without the error message I can just guess - it may be because of the `#shadow-root`. In [Cypress 4.8.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#4-8-0) support for testing shadow root was added. Take a look in the [documentation and description of .shadow()](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/experiments.html#Shadow-DOM). Update to Cypress 4.8.0 or higher, try adding this to your configuration and then try to get the element:

```
{
  "experimentalShadowDomSupport": true
}
```

Also, have a look at [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/144) closed issue on Cypress' GitHub. Hope it helps!

Comment: @P D thanks for the references. This worked  ```cy.get('df-messenger').shadow().find('#widgetIcon').click();```, ofcourse after setting ```experimentalShadowDomSupport: true```.